# Systematically use website with minimal manual input

Tags: python, image

I'm looking for a way to use python to repeat a simple process on a website automatically, and I also want to grab multiple pictures from a Google search.

Essentially, I'm trying to make a simple faceswap program. The website has a button that prompts you to choose an image, and I want this image to be a constant. The site has another similar button, but the other image will come a Google search (defined previously by the user) and will be different every time. The faceswap website will generate each result and display the new image. The user can manually cycle through the different results.

You run the program, choose an image, enter a phrase to find the other images, and browse the results. Is this possible with python?

Comment: yes. "everything" is possible with python.

Comment: Do you want some sort of web client interaction system like Selenium? https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ You are talking about an existing website, yes? You just want a python-scriptable way of interacting with it? Selenium.